# how to add Bootstrap into lineman ember template

Tags: node.js, ember.js, gruntjs, frontend, linemanjs

I just installed lineman and cloned the ember template from below URL.

```
https://github.com/linemanjs/lineman-ember-template
```

Then just added bootstrap css on the pages/index.us file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" media="all" />
```

I am getting 404 error on bootstrap.css, file is there in app/css/bootstrap.css file but I couldn't able to find the same file in generated folder.

Any one can help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default lineman concatenates the following:

```
app/css/**/*.css
```

&

```
vendor/css/**/*.css
```

to:

```
generated/css/app.css
```

So technically you should only have to include the `generated/css/app.css` in your html and Bootstrap should be included.

I'd recommend adding Bootstrap into the `vendor/css` folder.

Comment: I have 2 files app/css folder named as main.less, style.less but this content not generated in app.css file, help me pls..

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
yourProject>lineman fetch bootstrap
```